# Why is break statement not working in this situation (python)?

Tags: python, loops

I have two lists:

```
list1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

and I want to add List2 to List1 until we find the first sum that is larger than 10, print out the summation, and stops.

My code is:

```
for val1 in list1: 
   for val2 in list2:
      if val1+val2 > 10 :
        print (val1, val2, val1 + val2)
        break
      else:
        continue
```

But the result is:

```
0 11 11
1 10 11
2 9 11
3 8 11
4 7 11
5 6 11
```

How to make the loop stops at the first sum?
many thanks.
Note: I want to maintain the for...if loop structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'break' statement only breaks out of the first (EDIT: innermost) loop. Put it into a function and return a value like so:

```
def foo(list1, list2):
    for val1 in list1: 
        for val2 in list2:
            if val1+val2 > 10 :
                print (val1, val2, val1 + val2)
                return (val1 + val2) # or whatever you are interested in
            else:
                continue
```

Comment: *only breaks out of the first loop* -- really? i always thought it breaks the **nearst** loop.

Comment: @leiyang return does exit the function in any case returning whatever objects listed in its statement.

Comment: you are correct, that was phrased badly. The 'first' loop that it can break out of, which is the nearest/innermost, but not the first one when reading the code. Thanks for the correction, I edited the post!

Comment: Nice answer, this works. thanks!

Comment: @Danny: You can accept an answer as well

Answer (score 0):

**break** keyword is used to break out of **only one loop** to break out of **multiple loop** use `_break` `boolean` variable initially which is `False`

```
list1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10,11]

_break = False

for val1 in list1: 
   for val2 in list2:
      if val1+val2 > 10 :
        print (val1, val2, val1 + val2)
        _break = True
        if _break:
         break
   if _break:
       break
```

## Output:

```
0 11 11
```

Comment: Why not setting the variable equal to the predicate that breaks the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just maintain a flag variable to break out of the outer loop.

```
list1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10,11]
flag=0
for val1 in list1: 
    for val2 in list2:
        if val1+val2 > 10 :
            print (val1, val2, val1 + val2)
            flag=1
            break
        else:
            continue
    if(flag):
        break
```

If you don't have anything to execute after this, you can use exit() method to terminate the code.

```
list1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10,11]
for val1 in list1: 
    for val2 in list2:
        if val1+val2 > 10 :
            print (val1, val2, val1 + val2)
            exit()
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: Why not setting the variable equal to the predicate that breaks the loop. what does your answer add to the previous stating the same hack.

Comment: 'Why not setting the variable equal to the predicate that breaks the loop' -> I can't get you.    'what does your answer add to the previous stating the same hack.' -> There are many to solve a problem, its a coincidence.

Comment: `Flag  = val1+val2 > 10` will do the job as well and makes the logic connected to the predicate instead of having a constant added and disconnected from the logic. Anyway adding this constant is a bit hackish and is probably not the proper way to reach the goal.

Comment: The first answer works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's just breaking the inner loop.
If you want break both for loop then, You can use flag.

```
list1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10,11]
flag = 0
for val1 in list1: 
    for val2 in list2:
        if val1+val2 > 10 :
            print(val1, val2, val1 + val2)
            flag = 1
            break
        else:
            continue
     if flag:
         break
```